# How to contribute to a sub menu of context menu?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to define a sub menu entry in a viewpart's context menu.

I want to contribute a "Connection Profile" menu item  in this sub menu through my own plugin, and I hope other plugin can also contribute menu items  to this sub menu.

my plugin.xml

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:cn.ggfan.dmp.view.explorer">
         <menu
               id="new"
               label="New">
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:new?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="cn.ggfan.dmp.commands.addCP"
               label="Connection Profiles"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

it doest work. what's wrong with my code?

----------------------- **Edit** -----------------------
If I define the submenu like this, it works. but I still don't know how to contribute to my "new" sub menu in other plugins.

```xml
<menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:cn.ggfan.dmp.view.explorer">
         <menu
               id="new"
               label="new">
            <command
                  commandId="cn.ggfan.dmp.commands.addCP"
                  label="Connection  Profiles"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally, I got it, my "new" sub menu should be treated as a "popup" other than a "menu":

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:cn.ggfan.dmp.view.explorer">
         <menu
               id="cn.ggfan.new"
               label="New">
            <command
                  commandId="cn.ggfan.dmp.commands.addCP"
                  label="Connection Profile"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:cn.ggfan.new?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="cn.ggfan.dmp.commands.addTable"
               label="Table"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Comment: Yep... I should think you had two different menues with the same id - `new`.

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `menu:cn.ggfan.dmp.view.explorer` rather than `popup:cn.ggfan.dmp.view.explorer`.

See [Working with the menus extension point](http://tonnymadsen.blogspot.dk/2007/06/working-with-menus-extension-point.html) - a blog entry I wrote almost 6 years ago :-)

Comment: Thanks! @Tonny, but it still does't work. I want the "new" entry appear in the context menu(right click menu). And I cant visit your blog because of it was blokced by our national firewall :(